# VS2010 slowed to crawl when Hurricane Sandy killed internet connection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance

I'm in the greater New York area, and hurricane sandy has left us with power, but has killed our Internet connection. (I'm typing this on my ipad at a local McDonalds)

This has dramatically slowed VS2010 when starting a debug session within the IDE. There now seems to be a long pause...ten seconds for each dll...for every dll referenced in the project.  Now it takes several minutes every time we run our project.

The project itself has absolutely no Internet functionality...seems to be strictly related to VS 2010.

Disabling MS Symbol Server had no effect, and I could not find anything else in VS settings that would need the Internet.

**Edit**

We now have internet again, and startup times are back to around 20 seconds.

Previously, I also tried disabling Symbol Server again, and this time it did have a major effect - reduced startup time from 4 minutes to 1 minute.  Don't know why I did not see the same result the first time I tried.

Some testing with Win7 Resource Monitor indicates that VS is trying to talk to 224.0.0.251 and 252...Multicast DNS address and Link-local Multicast Name Resolution address respectively).

Also 239.255.255.250 (Simple Service Discovery Protocol).  Got the definitions by looking up the IP addresses on Wikipedia, but that does not really help me.

Any suggestions on how to track this down?

Comment: The title of your question suggests you should have more serious concerns :P

Comment: This is normally a symbol server delay.  Use a network spy tool to see what it is trying to talk to.  Oh, wait.